# For blenders, is Stainless Steel sturdier than Glass?

Tags: blender

My grandparents intend to blend warm (≤ 70°C = 158°F) soups in addition to fruits and vegetables. To them, glass feels more fragile and untrustworthy compared to stainless steel. So is stainless steel stouter?

They know that opacity is one disadvantage of Stainless Steel; they haven't lighted on a transparent stainless steel container/jar.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are going to blend *hot* soups, go with stainless. Glass can (and does!) crack due to the thermal issues. If they are religious about cooling their soups down to room temperature glass can be ok. But I've definitely had glass jars crack when blending hot soups. Tempered glass does not solve all problems.

Answer (score -2):

I'm surprised your grand parents did not have a glass blender before; they were and are still very common.

Glass jars are safe; I've not heard of reported problems with them; and have been in use for many, many years.

They are made with tempered glass and should not break during normal usage.

Also have a look at blender with plastic jars; maybe that could be a good solution.

Comment: I’ve seen glass ones explode like Pyrex on a gas ring! I’ve never had a steel one, I did for a long time have a plastic one I used for boiling hot foods, which was fine except for a tendency to spray past its seal, needing a tea towel folded & placed over the top to prevent the contents from becoming a bold fashion statement down the front of your whites :-)